# Difference of the two interface glDrawElements in JAVA GLES20.java

Tags: java, opengl-es-2.0

There are two interface glDrawElements:

```
public static native void glDrawElements( int mode, int count, int type, int offset);

public static native void glDrawElements( int mode, int count, int type, java.nio.Buffer indices);
```

Always Can the second interface be used, and the first interface does not draw anything.

How can I use the first interface correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The first function is useful when you are implementing VAO. In that case, you will be passing the indices in advance using glBindBuffer. Then during your glDrawElements the last element is usually 0 or you can give the offset from the buffer index.

glDrawElements in cpp has only one implementation, so java is wrapping the same function into 2.

Conclusion: The first one will be useful only when you use VAO.

Comment: Yes. As your answer, I created VAO, but indices buffer must be a parameter of glDrawElements. Otherwise, when I used the first interface with offset 0, my view was not shown.

Comment: If you are using VAO, it means that you are not going to send the indices every time. I think you have not properly setup vao.

Comment: At the begining, I generate a VAO and bind it. Then bind ARRAY_BUFFER for Vertex and Color array and enable the vertexAttribPointer, and bind ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER for indices. In the draw module, I bind the VAO and call glDrawElements with parameter offset 0.

Comment: Can I change vertex and indices buffer in the time of drawing? At begining, I initialize three points vertices. And the vertices' number will be updated to six. Does this update affects VAO?